# Ubuntu unable to resolve local domain

Tags: 17.04

Im a newbie in linux. I just setup my first ubuntu (v17.04) at work and im having this issue where the system isn't able to resolve ping to FQDN of the local domain, Example:

If pinging: Hostname i get a replay and i see that the ping solved the host name to the FQDN.

If i ping: HostName.Domain.local i get "ping: HostName.Domain.local: Name or service not known"

I found something about Avahi and i edited the  /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf but that didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you try pinging Hostname.local?

Comment: Yes that worked, it resolved to the local computer IP

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf has these lines:  nameserver 127.0.0.53
search ilient-hq.local

Comment: Another thing i notice that pinging some hosts on the local network just by using the hostname will take up to 10 seconds be for the ping gets a response.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i bypass the issue by disabling systemd-resolved and just configuring dnsmasq as the default resolver.

I didn't get to the bottom of it but from what i read on line systemd-resolve has an issue with domain that have .local in them ( domain.local)